# Updating Devise User Attributes Not As Current User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm creating a super simple "admin" section on a rails 4.2 project. I have used Devise 3.4.1.

I have created an attribute called role for each user, and would like for "admin" users to be able to change the role for other users. I have created a form, but when I submit it I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#update
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #22):
20  # Proxy to devise map name
21 def resource_name
22  devise_mapping.name
23 end
24 alias :scope_name :resource_name
```

Here is my form, user is a bloc variable for @user.each do |user| (@user is User.all):

```
<%= form_for(user, url: update_role_path(user), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select(:role, @roles.collect {|role| [role] }, {:include_blank => 'Please select an item'}) %>
    <%= f.submit "Change Role", class: "btn btn-primary" %>        
<% end %>
```

Here is my route:

```
put '/admin' => 'devise/registrations#update', as: "update_role"
```

I've tried several different things but always end up back at this error. Any help on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going about this the wrong way. Instead of calling against registration, create your own users controller with an update action and update it there through users#update instead.

The divise controller is specific to registration actions etc.

Comment: I would like to also point out that this makes it easier to ensure that the user updating the roll is indeed an admin as well using `before_filter`

Comment: Ah! That makes complete sense. Thank you.